# Excluding from query all rows related with a value IN a subquery result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with these tables (omitting columns not relevant to the question, all the columns are primary keys):

```
recipes (name, ...)
ingredients (name, ...)
composition (rec_name,ing_name)
```

Composition relates recipes and ingredients by their (unique) names.

I want to select all recipes whose ingredients are all present in a given subquery that produces a whitelist ( or exclude all recipes containing a non-whitelisted ingredient ).

So far I came up with this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT recipes.name 
FROM recipes,ingredients, composition 
WHERE recipes.name = composition.rec_name AND 
    ingredients.name = composition.ing_name

GROUP BY ingredients.name

HAVING ingredients.name = ANY (**SUBQUERY**)
```

In this way I can exclude non-whitelisted ingredients, but the recipe is returned due to the other whitelisted ingredients (if I remove `DISTINCT` each recipes shows up as many times as many "good" ingredients it's made of). How can I totally remove a recipe as soon as it contains a non-whitelisted ingredient?

I'm not including the subquery in the question because it's rather long and it's tested and it works, it begins like `SELECT ingredients.name FROM ...` so there are no type problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the recipe contains all the ingredients in the subquery, then you can simply count the number of times that ingredients are *not* in the list.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT c.rec_name
FROM composition c
GROUP BY c.rec_name
HAVING sum(ing_name not in (**SUBQUERY**)) = 0;
```

Comment: Ok, it works! Thanks, I was stuck thinking in my way and couldn't think of counting ingredients